# universal covering group construction

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

Wikipedia gives the following intuitive description of the universal covering group:

"Concretely, the universal covering group of H is the space of homotopy classes of paths in H with pointwise multiplication of paths. The covering map sends each path class to its endpoint."

My question is why the covering map described in this way well defined? It doesn't seem like it would be because we can have two paths with different endpoints that are homotopic?

Comment: I think the homotopy here should fix the endpoint.

Comment: @Bonbon That would make sense... then I would agree that it's well defined